# Why is potassium cation harder than copper?

Tags: ions, hsab

According to HSAB theory, the smaller radius and the less polarizable an acid is, the harder it is. According to Wikipedia, the ionic radii of $\ce{ K+}$ is much larger than $\ce{Cu+}$, which makes sense because d-electrons are poor shielders. Also, $\ce{Cu+}$ has larger electron density but it has a higher effective nuclear charge in comparison to potassium ion because of the poor shielding ability of d-electrons. Yet why is $\ce{K+}$  ion considered hard while $\ce{Cu+}$ ions are considered soft?

Comment: I have misspelt harder in the title can any privileged user/OP take a look.

Answer (score 7):

$\ce{Cu+}$ has a kernel of $\ce{K+}$, with an extra 10 protons in the nucleus and a $\mathrm{3d^{10}}$ electron shell around it. $\ce{Cu+}$ is smaller because it has more positive charge pulling those electrons in. But size isn't everything!

The first ionization potential of potassium ($\pu{4.34 V}$) is much lower than the first ionization potential of copper ($\pu{7.73 V}$). But from there on, the situation changes: Second ionization potential: $\pu{31.63 V}$ for $\ce{K}$ vs $\pu{20.29 V}$ for $\ce{Cu}$; third ionization potential: $\pu{45.72 V}$ for $\ce{K}$ vs $\pu{36.83 V}$ for $\ce{Cu}$; fourth ionization potential: $\pu{60.91 V}$ for $\ce{K}$ vs $\pu{55.2 V}$ for $\ce{Cu}$; and fifth ionization potential: $\pu{82.66 V}$ for $\ce{K}$ vs $\pu{79.9 V}$ for $\ce{Cu}$. It is not till the sixth ionization potential that potassium is again easier to ionize than copper: $\pu{100.0 V}$ for $\ce{K}$ vs $\pu{103 V}$ for $\ce{Cu}$.

So, although the smaller size of the $\ce{Cu+}$ ion suggests that it would be harder (after all, it's stuffed with more electrons!), it turns out that the $\ce{Cu+}$ ion has a softer (*i.e.* more easily ionized, therefore more easily polarized) outer skin.

Perhaps this is not predictable unless you take into account more than just ionic radii, but at least it is explainable.